# Ubuntu not Booting and package missing

Tags: boot, gnome, package-management

My Ubuntu is not booting anymore, after I wrote this command on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse
```

Then logged off.

Now it keeps trying to boot, but fail in some background-proccess on the booting screen (I can see the ones that fails if I press some key in the booting screen).

When I go to Ubuntu Advanced Options->Ubuntu (recovery mode) and try to do something, like repair packages, it says:

```
"libapt-pkgso.4.12: cannot open shared file"[...]
```

Or something like that.

I'll try to be more clear:

The apt-get is missing on my console, I can't get things by apt-get!

What can I do? 
How can I install this package without booting Ubuntu?
Is there any kind of 'recovery point' in Ubuntu that I can use?

I can't lost my files inside Ubuntu's partition!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*OPTION 1*

If you haven't tried this, give it a shot:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libapt-pkg4.12
```

*OPTION 2*

Otherwise, you may have to do it manually.  See if Comment # 4 in [Upgrade problem, apt-get update leads to error message: libapt-pkg.so.4.12: file](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2020530&p=12086463#post12086463) helps you.  (Note that this is for Ubuntu 12.04, so you may have to make adjustments for your version of Ubuntu).

You may need another computer to download the required files to put them onto a USB stick, so you can repair your system.  You can get the libapt-pkg4.12 files for Ubuntu 13.04 by clicking the amd64 or i386 links here: [libapt-pkg4.12](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libapt-pkg4.12)

Extract (using `dpkg -x`) and copy the files from the deb package to your computer using super user privileges.

*OPTION 3*

Instead of extracting the deb file, just manually reinstall the libapt-pkg4 package.

1. On another computer, go to [libapt-pkg4.12](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libapt-pkg4.12) and download the libapt-pkg4.12 package for Ubuntu 13.04 by clicking the amd64 or i386 (depending on your architecture).
2. Copy these *.deb file onto a USB stick.
3. On the computer you want to repair, open a terminal window, and type `su -` to elevate your privileges to super user level (since you mentioned sudo doesn't work, but su does).4. Insert the USB stick into your computer that you need to repair and open a terminal window.
4. Type `cd /media`
5. If you see your USB folder or files in `/media`, just skip to step 6.  If you don't see anything in `/media`, then type `dmesg` and press enter.  Look towards the bottom, and you will see a bunch of lines specifing the USB device you just plugged in.  Near the botom of the output, you will see a line similar to "`[27161.701717]  sdb: sdb1`".  Note the "`sdb1`" part (it may be different on your computer).  Now, manually mount the USB stick using these steps (replace `sdb1` with your your own value obtained from the `dmesg` command).

   `mkdir /media/temp`

   `mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/temp -o uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137`

   `cd /media/temp/`
6. Type `ls -l` to see your *.deb file. (If you don't see your *.deb file, you may have to `cd` into sub-directories on your USB stick).
7. If you have downloaded the x32 bit package, type the following to install it:

   `dpkg -i libapt-pkg4.12_0.9.7.7ubuntu4_i386.deb`
8. Or, if you have downloaded the x64 bit package, type the following to install it:

   `dpkg -i libapt-pkg4.12_0.9.7.7ubuntu4_amd64.deb`

Comment: I'll try to do that, but one question at manually installing the pkg: How can i copy the file from the usb via console, heh?

Comment: The USB should be mounted under your `/media` directory.

Comment: Can you help with it? I'm newbie at Ubuntu and I dunno how to copy files from a partition to another

Comment: OK, I added detailed instructions as OPTION 3 in the answer above.  I figured you could just manually reinstall the entire package using dpkg -i, instead of actually extracting and copying each file.  If the dpkg-i approach doesn't work, you can try option 2.

Answer (score 0):

From the recovery mode , drop to root shell. then type this command

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libapt-pkgso.4.12
```

restart your PC and try again.

Comment: I can't sudo (ok, but I've gone SU), and when i try to apt-get it says:
"libapt-pkgso.4.12: cannot open shared file. File or directory not found"
Resuming: the 'apt-get' command and some others like 'sudo' are missing :/